# Global variable not picking up change within function

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code I picked up from html5rocks for loading a file which you drag and drop onto to your page, and I'm modifying it so that it reads the file into a string, which I then muck about with, and output to the page.  That bit is working, but I also need to be able to pick up the string outside the function that created it, and I can't.

I think this is either a scope problem, or perhaps some sort of callback issue. Anyway here is the code:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    var output = [];
    var OutString = []; // < --my variable that I want to use

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (f.name.match('\.csv')) { // if 1
            var Filename = decodeURI(escape(f.name));
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) { 
                return function (e) {        
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    var FileLines = contents.split("\n");
                    var LineCount = FileLines.length;
                    OutString = '<table id="mytab" border = "1" width = "90%"><tr>';
                    var ColCount = 1;
                    for (var i = 0; i < LineCount; ++i) {
                        OutString = // I format a table here..
                    }
                    OutString += '</tr></table>';

                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = [OutString].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsText(f);
            // if format up a word document using xml here 
            testFunc = // I want to read the contents of OutString here

            // this creates the button that opens the finished document 
            var OutPutLine = "<a href='data:application/msword;charset=UTF-8, " + encodeURIComponent(TestFunc) + "' ><input id='Button1' type='button' value='Open printable sheet1' /></a>";
            output.push(OutPutLine);

        } else {
            // this triggers if its not a csv file that drag n drops
            output.push('<strong>', escape(f.name), ' is not a comma seperated (.csv) file!!!!</strong>');
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

I don't mind if I get the string form a variable, or pick it up from the document (it's a table), but at the moment I can't do either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `OutString` is declared inside `handleFileSelect`(it has the `var`-keyword in front of it), which means it will only be availible to that function (or functions declared inside that function).

To fix it, you could declare your `OutString` outside `handleFileSelect`, making it availible for access outside the function.

Alternatively you could get the `<table>`-element by referencing the `id`, that you're assigning to it:

```
document.getElementById('mytab')
```

---

You also set a callback for the `FileReaders` `onload`-event. This is done by a self-calling `function`, to prevent issues with scope. A new `function` is returned by the self-calling one and that `function` is used as the callback for the `onload`-event. As this is an event, it will only be called when that event fires, which might be before or after you access `OutString` (outside `handleFileSelect`). You could add a callback to `handleFileSelect` like this:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt, callback) {
    //Removed some code to shorten the example

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (f.name.match('\.csv')) { // if 1
            var Filename = decodeURI(escape(f.name));
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theFile, onloadCallback) { 
                return function (e) {        
                    //Removed some code to shorten the example
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

                    if( onloadCallback && typeof onloadCallback === 'function' )
                        onloadCallback();
                };
            })(f, callback);

            //Removed some code to shorten the example
        } else {
            //Removed some code to shorten the example
    }
    //Removed some code to shorten the example
}
```

Comment: I'm also trying to pick it up from within that function - aren't I?

Comment: If you declare it outside the `function` it would still be accesible inside the `function` (but would also be availible to other `functions` within the same scope).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried moving the OutString declaration above handleFileSelect, but that didn't work.  The document.getElementById('mytab') returned null.  This thing is driving me mad!

Comment: oh, a weird thing happened: the first file I load, Outsrting is empty, then for each subsequent file, outstring displays the contents of the previous file.

Comment: Sounds like the place you try to re-access `OutString` gets executed before you actually assign the value to `OutString`.

Comment: Yes, I'll have a play with it and if I get it working, I'll accept your answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: you don't happen to know which bit of the program is causing the function (e) (...  }(f) to execute, do you?

Comment: I don't see that part in your included code sample, so I can't say anything about that.

Comment: its the whole section from line 12 to line 26.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I'll post something about it in my answer.

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer.